# Replace names of array objects dynamically by string content

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

To reduce my last question (it was a bit complicated). Is it possible to change the names of "array objects" dynamically?

I have a list of variables (structure must stay like this way):

```
var markers = []
var markerHouse = ... markers.push(markerHouse);
var markerAnimal = ... markers.push(markerAnimal);
var markerCar = ... markers.push(markerCar);
// aso.
```

I tried lots of ways to change the array object names, like this one:

```
var NewMarkers = "markerHouse, markerAnimal"; // string content, generated by a function
var NewMarkersArray = NewMarkers.split(","); // create array of this string
var NewGroup = L.layerGroup([NewMarkersArray]); // request for array of objects
```

The result of `NewGroup` is:

```
L.layerGroup(["markerHouse", "markerAnimal"]);
```

And I get a "TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for "_leaflet_id" in "markerHouse" ...

But what I need is:

```
L.layerGroup([markerHouse, markerAnimal]);
```

Comment: If you need to access variables like that, you shouldn't be using variables. Instead, use either an array of values, or else an object with property names. You can do what you want cleanly then.

Comment: How is `NewMarkers` being created? Also, what is this supposed to mean `var markerHouse = ... markers.push(markerHouse);`?

Comment: I am with you, but leaflet seems not to support a classic "object way with property names", if I am right.

Comment: You probably need an object with `const marker = { house: "value",  car: "value2", animal: "", etc}` and then create an array of filtered values based on your requirement

Comment: @adiga I got this values by a function loop, that search for specific content. The rest of the "var markerHouse = ...." are just coordinates aso.

Comment: Probably something like this might work for you: `const markers = { markerHouse: value, markerAnimal: value, markerCar: value }` and then you can get `const values = NewMarkers.split(", ").map(k =>markers[k] )` and then `L.layerGroup(values)`. This can probably improved based on how `NewMarkers` is created but you have not shared those details.

Answer (score 1):

Using eval() as suggested in other questions is considered a bad practice.

The most straightforward way to retrieve a global variable by it's string name is from 'window'. A global variable is actually a property of the 'window' object.

So you could do:

```
L.layerGroup( [ window["markerHouse"], window["markerAnimal")] ]);
```

And with dynamic variable names:

```
var dynamicallyGeneratedArrayOfVarNames = "markerHouse,markerAnimal".split(',');
L.layerGroup( [ window[dynamicallyGeneratedArrayOfVarNames[0]], window[dynamicallyGeneratedArrayOfVarNames[1])] ]);
```

See snippet below:

```js
var markerHouse = 'markerHouse content';
var markerAnimal = 'markerAnimal content'

console.log(window['markerHouse']);
console.log(window['markerAnimal']);

// And with dynamically retrieved names
var NewMarkers = "markerHouse, markerAnimal"; // string content, generated by a function
var NewMarkersArray = NewMarkers.split(", "); // create array of this string
console.log(window[NewMarkersArray[0]])
console.log(window[NewMarkersArray[1]])
```

Still, if you have the luxury of refactoring the initial code, the best practice would be to store the variables by name on creation e.g.:

```
const myvars = {}
myvars.markerHouse = "any type of marker house data"
myvars.markerAnimal = "any type of marker animal data"

L.layerGroup( [ myvars["markerHouse"], myvars["markerAnimal")] ]);
```

Comment: This is assuming their code is at the global level and not inside a function or a class

Comment: Thx for your example. If I am right, this way also only works If I know the exact string "words" and the amount of it, right? In my situation this string content and amount is generated dynamically.

Comment: No not really, you can use a string variable instead of a name. Let me update the example.

Comment: Hm, when I use this way, I always get "undefined" for the array at the moment. Have to search why this happens.

Comment: I am sry, but it is not working for me. Event the "static" example calls an "undefined".

Comment: Check the updated snippet. Make sure you are splitting the string by the correct delimitter eg "," vs ", " (notice the space after the comma)

Comment: Uhh ... `this` in a function cannot access local variables that way.

Comment: Yes, that seems so be the problem. What every I do, I get "undefined" by this way.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, this won't work in function.

Comment: But the "window" way works, thanks for that! The problem at this way is, that I need to know the amount of "strings". There is no dynamic way for it, right?

Comment: This depends on the way the string are retrieved. In your example, you could check the length of NewMarkersArray and use a for loop.

Comment: "A variable's scope is 'this'". That's not how `this` works.

Comment: @GeorgeMarios Thx for the loop idea, I will try it.

Comment: @TrevorDixon Yes, that was a wrong choice of terms. I have edited the answer so as not to be misdirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need eval?

```
L.layerGroup([eval("markerHouse"), eval("markerAnimal")]);
```

Comment: Definitely doesn't *need* `eval()`.

Comment: I read lots of "warnings" about "eval" ... not sure, if this is the way I should go? And my problem is, that this "NewMarkers" string is generated dynamical (through a loop), so I don't know the exact words and count of it.

Comment: BTW you can loop the array
const a = '2 + 2';
const b = '2 + 3'
const arr = [a,b];
arr.map(el => {
console.log(eval(el));
})

@pepe Yes, eval is not sure because you can run code from a string so you need to be sure it is safe. Alternative is Function (but concept is the same).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!

Answer (score 0):

Keep your values in an object:

```
const allMarkers = {
    house: whatever,
    animal: whatever,
    boat: whatever,
    // ...
 };

 let markerNames = ["house", "boat"];

 let markers = markerNames.map(name => allMarkers[name]);
```

Then:

```
  let newGroup = L.layerGroup(markers);
```

The `allMarkers` object contains the actual *values* corresponding to the named variables in your original code. They can be accessed by name dynamically because objects in JavaScript inherently provide that feature. The list of marker names can therefore be transformed into a list of the actual values with that simple `.map()` call.

Comment: Yes I wish I could go that route but in my scenario it's not an option - but thx.

Comment: @Pepe if you start out with separate variables, you can copy their values into an object as described in this answer. You do have the option.

Comment: Interesting way, didn't know that. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't change what you've got, then I'd probably maintain a map of keys for every variable.

```
const vars = {
  'markerHouse': markerHouse,
  'markerAnimal': markerAnimal,
};
```

Or even nicer:

```
const vars = {markerHouse, markerAnimal};
```

Then:

```
var NewGroup = L.layerGroup(NewMarkersArray.map(v => vars[v]));
```

If that's infeasible, then you'll have to use eval or window['markerHouse']. Those both feel terrible though and suggest has gone wrong somewhere along the way.

Comment: Looks similar to "Pointys" idea? Interesting, didn't know that this is possible. Will try it.